# Could not sign data, Message is larger than modulus (but it doesn't seem that way)

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, signature

newbie here, I am trying out Java's signature functions, and running into strange behavior.

```
Modulus_Base64_Url = "1ry2pHOcOzyozMNod89z0hoqbLaW2oxFvKIgUir0r2BR-C4k4vhaZJxFaDc_kawUVLHTk4vdQqIakZ-WnWM5RazjI5WBnUapHr7XCAEI2_lBjvmJRueV0nJNwhkLnU1U2xPX9xquWLpNO9iT7CpYJOe6K1rj8Clc7SnTGoHP3DT4jbnwF2eGTLF07_MrelqPO2xh0qg2XK1pNjwO1Z-4di6L0XTGkN7-hMTLoRDCPey8AcFr_LGJEfd1Fo2FOhDWwN2mL7ZxEYM8n1kMUJCAkCjnUKJnRjUS6qM1L181jBq1iXy33DvkyP50XCeE2-J9ee6z02-L787Smtrmya330w";

PrivateExponent_Base64_Url = "DgRnj7iUPDGreyJOUXPTRaW7mzkYA9AgRT34CiUPr9sDvsWUVtSLYgHpbfIdTi8DbLvm6by5hr36KgNW25M8i9XLReleepvAMmeWtckLgQB2TRTw5xX666_Wb5Me9Pe1UE-tS04Mj3Ip1HxAu6vP8SjHOElIk8a_cCPIyfQrU15rK4d71VuwObBeA2g7pJtC7h6WBxEHg0K73xHDKsesDWLE2IbhrRKPLFPtXSIb9ySWgqEXEmX0nX5n6Q1zPwAvKURrpX58XDpUVoVX7YfusbhKDfRE_1GJ-5SbuTNQorZFFTSvrZNCvZY6FDzuZtHOHluwT1OGNjLXLr-iIX2-IQ";

byte[] Message = new byte[]{48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57};

Modulus = java.util.Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(Modulus_Base64_Url);
PrivateExponent = java.util.Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(PrivateExponent_Base64_Url);

keySpec = java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec(java.math.BigInteger(Modulus), java.math.BigInteger(PrivateExponent));

keyFactory = java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
signature = java.security.Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update(Message);
signature.sign();
```

This code fails at the signature.sign() statement, at the very end. The error I get is

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Message is larger than modulus
```

However, the Message here is just 10 bytes long.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: None of this code compiles. Please, do not type code from memory, always copy and paste code that compiles, or, if asking about a compiler error than copy&paste the code that won't compile.

Comment: Most likely the problem is your failure to use the [sign-magnitude constructor for `BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-byte:A-). Your modulus is being interpreted as a negative number.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try and/or research?

Comment: @JamesKPolk The question is of course why the private key construction doesn't fail...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I was surprised as well. Any input taken from userland should be sanity checked.

Comment: @captainjohnsparrow When you use RSA via `Signing` the message that is too large is not the 10 bytes, but the SHA-256 hash of those 10 bytes - hence the message RSA is applied on has at least 256bit = 32 bytes (plus padding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the modulus is turned negative when you decode it to `BigInteger`. Moduli are often stored as unsigned big endian values, while Java treats an array as signed big endian value.

However, you can simply *force* the sign to be positive by using `new BigInteger(1, value)`, where the `1` signifies the positive sign.